# Phantom delete votes?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

From time to time, I go to the report of pending deleted. I find a question that claims to have a delete vote. When I go to the question, it has none -- and in fact is hours to days away from being deletable. What's happening?

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618039/how-to-make-the-arrows-keys-act-as-another-keys-closed).

Answer (score 2):

That questions is [deleted by OP once, and undeleted himself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2618039/revisions), so the question is just not in the list anymore. I think thats why you seeing None.

Comment: Is it just temporarily hanging around on the list?

Comment: @bmargulies, as far as I know those lists are cached, which makes time gap between the actual votes and list.